# Google Inbox cuts off anything after `=` in a mailto: body parameter

Tags: android, href, mailto, inbox, google-inbox

When opening a `mailto:` link from Android using Inbox, Inbox will cut out anything after a `=` in the `body` parameter. E.g. `mailto:?subject=argh&body=whereitcutsoff=anythingafterisremoved` becomes `whereitcutsoff` in the body of the email.

Anyone know of a workaround or fix for this? I'm trying to add a URL with UTM parameters to the body of an email and they're basically all being cut off.

Answer (score 2):

The value for the body parameter, needs to be URL-encoded.